# Javascript closure returning string instead of function

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to write a simple `compose` function that takes a series of functions, and composes them like so:

```
compose(func1, func2, func3)(n) === func1(func2(func3(n)))
```

I do so by recursing through a rest parameter,

```
var compose = function(...args) {
    return (n) => {
        if (args.length) {
            return args[0](compose(args.slice(1)));
        } else {
            return n;
        }
    };
};
```

I then attempt to compose a new function made up of a series of other functions,

```
var plusOneAndTwo = compose((n) => n + 1, (n) => n + 2);
plusOneAndTwo(1);
```

Instead of returning 4, I get back the body of the inner, anonymous function inside of `compose` as a string,

```
"(n) => {
        if (args.length) {
            return args[0](compose(args.slice(1)));
        } else {
            return n;
        }
    }1"
```

Note the `"1"` at the end of the string! I have no idea why this is happening, and in particular I'm perplexed by how a 1 is getting appended to the end of that.

Any clarification is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `compose` returns a function, yes. You're passing the return value of `compose`, which is a function, to `args[0]()`. I don't think it's a good idea to use `compose` recursively. I'd simply `.reduce` the `args` instead.

Comment: @deceze I expect compose to return a function. But when I call the function returned by compose, I get it's body as a string. That's what I'm confused about. edit: Ah okay, I see what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: `compose(args.slice(1))` You don't actually call the function returned by compose here as you do in the initial call, you use the function as the argument to args[0] instead of the result of calling it.

Comment: No, the crux is at `args[0](compose(...))`. This passes a function to `(n) => n + 1`, which concatenates `1` to the function body.

Comment: @deceze Thanks a lot, that makes a ton of sense, mystery explained!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs in the recursive call to compose. 
In particular, you are not passing the parameter `n` to it (as also suggested by others above). Furthermore, you need to expand the rest parameter in the call.

You should use something like:

```
return args[0](compose(...args.slice(1))(n))
```

In your case, you are simply returning:

```
return args[0](compose(args.slice(1)));
```

In your example you call `compose((n) => n + 1, (n) => n + 2);`. Compose then returns a function taking `n` as a parameter. In this function, args.length becomes 1 (i.e. true-is), args[0] becomes `(n) => n + 1` and args.slice(1) becomes `[(n) => n + 2]`.

Next, you call this returned function with the parameter `n = 1`. As args.length is 1, the if() statement will go into the if() case. In this if case, it will call args[0] with the argument `compose(args.slice(1))`.

In this recursive call, compose(args.slice(1)) is evaluated to a function, taking n as a parameter and the same function body. 
This function is then given as the parameter `n` to args[0] (in the outer call). Recall that args[0] in this scenario is the function `(n) => n + 1`.

Thus the call as a whole is equivalent to:

```
// returned from the recursive call to compose(args.slice(1))
var n = (n) => {
        if (args.length) {
            return args[0](compose(args.slice(1)));
        } else {
            return n;
        }
}
// applied to arg[0] == (n) => n + 1
return n + 1
```

This means that the code will attempt to add a function with the number 1. 
In JavaScript adding a function and a number results in both objects coerced into a string. Casting a number into a string is trivial, casting a function into a string returns the function source code. These strings are then added to give the return value you saw: The function body as a string with the 1 at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to call the composed function:

```
 return args[0](compose(...args.slice(1))(n));
```

Or without recursion it'll be:

```
 const compose = (...fns) => start => fns.reduceRight((acc, fn) => fn(acc), start);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a different approach by returning a new function or returning the last function for calling with arguments.

```js
const
    compose = (...fns) => fns.length
        ? v => compose(...fns.slice(0, -1))(fns.pop()(v))
        : v => v,
    fn1 = n => n * 5,
    fn2 = n => n + 2,
    fn3 = n => n * 7;

console.log(fn1(fn2(fn3(1))));
console.log(compose(fn1, fn2, fn3)(1));
```